# how to execute php through ajax and get only value not html

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I would like to get variable values from PHP using AJAX in jquery into textbox i.e. not the html just value. I want to store that value in another variable in jquery then show that value into the textbox in html. I know that I should use the following code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#product').click(function(){
    var category_id = $('#product').val();
    if(category_id != 0)
    {
      $.ajax({
        type:'post',
       dataType:'json'
        url:'productpricecheck.php',
        data:{id:category_id},
        cache:false,

        success: function(returndata){
        
     $('#unitprice').html(returndata);
     
        }
       
      });
    }
  })

 });
```

```html
<?php 

include("config.php");
   
$getCategories = "SELECT Product_MSRP FROM products
                        WHERE Product_Id = '".$_POST["id"]."'";
              
                        $res = selectMultiRecords($getCategories);
            
                        for($i=0;$i<count($res);$i++)
                        {
         
                          $price = $res[$i]['Product_MSRP'];
   
                  echo json_encode($price);
                       }
?>
```

Comment: remove your `dataType:'json'` and don't encode result as json `echo $price;`

Comment: i have done that but i need the value in integers  and to be stored in variable so i can perform other multiplication with it... but i am just gettin that value in string or html

Comment: use javascript `parseInt()`
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp

Comment: how and where i can use that???

Comment: if you want to perform multiplication in javascript function, you should declare a variable `var price = parseInt(returnData);` and use `price` for multiplication

Comment: why cant i get the value through .val but .html or .text

Comment: it depends on your HTML structure. `val()` is only works with HTML element which store `value` like `<input type="text" value="this is the value">`. otherwise, `html()` and `text()` is for non-value HTML element like `<textarea>This is the value</textarea>`. hope you notice `value=" "` positioning

Comment: not performing any multiplication through that